# C++ std::streambuf::pubseekpos(): check if random access is supported

Tags: c++, feature-detection, random-access, streambuf

While writing a generic function taking a reference to an `std::streambuf`, I'd like to check if the supplied buffer is tied to something supporting random access or not and optimize the treatment accordingly, i.e. check if moving around the stream with `pubseekpos()` is available or not.

I might have overlooked that in the documentation. Would you happen to have a crystal clear solution, other than late-discovering if it works or not based on the result of the latter method (which returns `-1` in case of failure to seek, which could have other causes)?

Available docs:

- https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pubseekpos/
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubseekpos

Thanks in advance. Regards.

---

(Edit #GIJD after first comment)

Even if I'm not really glad about it, you've got a good point here. The same as "rather than testing if a file exists before opening it, open it and process error_status/exceptions" (as a race condition is always possible between the test and the opening otherwise).

OK, the actual function call by itself might indeed be the best proof over some feature flag existence test (that might also be wrongly set, even if unlikely if the code was tested duly... well, I just read what I wrote, yeah, well, as if code is always duly tested... OK ha ha, better test the function directly yes yes).

But, still, a -1 return value might mean error, not lack of random access, but one might argue that the result is the same, I won't be able to do random access if it fails whatever the reason, feature lack or some error. Thus, I'll have to fall back to a one-pass stream read anyway.

Thanks. Regards.

---

Comment: `pubseekpos` calls the `virtual seekpos()` member function,. so I think it'll be hard to come up with a foolproof check without actually testing it.

Comment: See edit #GIJD above.

Comment: What does #GIJD mean?

Comment: #GIJD means nothing, it's just a short random unique string you can search for. A sorta manual reference/link to the text above. It's a way of linking to text when you don't have access to hypertext, an apogee in such a wiki-like environment :-) If there's a way though, I could have overlooked, I'm interested.

Comment: I see. That kind of linkage is not used here on SO so the question looks strange with that in it. Comments are also not supposed to carry vital information about the question and they are sometimes scrubbed. If that happens it would make that link in the question extra confusing. I suggest an edit :-)